# DVD not working on Windows Media Player

Tags: dvd, windows-media-player, regional-settings

I've made a DVD with Adobe Encore and it play fine on VLC, other media player, and my DVD player connected to my TV. The only exception is Windows Media Player, which give an error about a wrong region code (that I have double checked on encore and I know is valid)
How do I fix this? there is come info software to see the region code of a DVD and a DVD player, so I can check the DVD player on my computer? I'm going nuts there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end i had to completely rebuild the dvd from scratch, but at end it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `My Computer` or `Computer`, and right click on any optical drive, then choose `Properties`.

Go to the `Hardware` tab and double click on the optical drive you want to choose.

Find the `Region` tab and you should be able to change it there.

Comment: This is an heavy change (you have only 5). My dvd reader is set to "no region" and other dvd works fine with it. I need to make my dvd working with media player "out of the box" :(